# Unity AR Foundation: how to influence the renderorder

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, augmented-reality

in my AR application I want to render a model on top over another. Is there any method or variable to influence this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there are at least two options:

#### z-test set to `always`

this has to be set on the shader of the materal your model is using. [Here's](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ZTest.html) the documentation from unity, but there are also some guides online how to write a shader with custom z-test.

#### two Cameras

This is done by having two cameras. One is your ARCamera and a second one that always at the same pose as the ARCamera. This could for example be done by setting the 2nd camera as a child of the ARCamera with Identity Pose. Then you can create a special Layer for example "Always In Front" and assign the model to it. Then set the cullings Masks accordingly for both cameras such that the 2nd camera only renders the model and the ARCamera only everything else. There might be some overhead when rendering two cameras with this solution.

Your problem has a similar solution to preventing weapons clipping in FPS games. As seen in [this blogpost](https://alexey-anufriev.com/blog/using-multiple-cameras-in-unity/) .

Comment: hey, thanks for your help and sorry for my late response. Had to fix some other problems. I tried the secon option with the two cameras and encountered the problem that I just can see the conted from the second camera which contains the frontlayer stuff. The modell I wanted to render with the MainCamera in the back wont appear.

Comment: Did you set the clear flag correctly? (Depth only).

Answer (score 0):

[MainCamera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOlGM.png)
[SecondCamera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fKYp.png)
The two picutes show the properties I set in the inspector for each camera. Therefore I tried it also in two diffrent ways but neither made a diffrence.

I: SecondCamera is the Child of the MainCamera

II: SecondCamera and MainCamera are both on the same hierarchy level in the ARSessionOrigin.

Comment: Wait, so this has worked? I don't think it should work...